# MacPorts auto-update failed, OS X Mavericks, exit code 12

Tags: macos, terminal, macports

I'm trying to auto-update my MacPorts and recently upgraded to Mavericks. I've already run

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and agreed to the license. Then I do the following and my update doesn't work

```
port -v selfupdate
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done
rsync: mkstemp "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/.base.tar.ytBeLt" failed: Permission denied (13)
inflate returned -3 (137 bytes)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/token.c(419) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (31 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [generator=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 12
Error: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

I've searched the web trying to figure out what this all means. A few responses said I was on wireless internet which had a firewall, but I've tried it on two different networks now and I don't think that is the problem. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Macports advises to start with a clean macports installation when upgrading your OS (http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration). It's probably going to be faster than solving all the problems you might encounter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this command as a sudoer?

`sudo port selfupdate`

I had the same problem and I got to solve it this way.